# Как очистить cache hibernate'а

Tags: hibernate, java

как очистить кэш hibernate.
Пробовал так:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictQueryRegions();
org.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictCollectionRegions();
org.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictEntityRegions();
```

Не помогло.
Проверял так: вызывал эти методы (вместе, по отдельности), затем вызывал сборку мусора несколько раз (до тех пор пока его вызов приносил результат), а затем смотрел дамп памяти, а все запросы что я выполнял - все там.

Cache 2-го уровня отключал/очищал - никак не влияет

Версия hibernate'а 3.6.8.Final

Перед закрытием сессии делается

```
session.clear()
```

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: session.flush() ??

Comment: нет, не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В хибернейте лежит тикет на этот `issue`, подробности можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1012488)*

Таким образом, сейчас имеет смысл использовать старый интерфейс для очистки кэша через `SessionFactory`, т.е:

```
// Или evictQueries(region), но region необходимо получить.
sessionFactory.evictQueries();

Map allClassMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
for (EntityPersister persister : allClassMetadata.values()) {
    if (persister.hasCache()) {
        sessionFactory.evictEntity(persister.getCache().getRegionName());
    }
}

// Аналогично для 'evictCollection' через 'getAllCollectionMetadata'
```

Если все - в `default cache region`, то просто `evictQueries`, `evictEntity`, `evictCollections`.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 0):

У меня была проблема с обновлением данных. Не выводил обновленные данные. Решил так:

```
session.clear();
Cache cache = sessionFactory.getCache();
if (cache != null) {
    cache.evictAllRegions();
}
```